# How I can create a log channel for my discord bot and how I can get records on the log channel?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have some disсord servers and I need the bot to create a log channel into which my bot is able to write the data I will indicate in the code.

Comment: You really should give us some of your code to see how far you have come already. Asking without having a specific problem on hand is not what this site is useful for.
If you just want to know how to implement such a thing you could read some blog posts; here we can only help by advising how to make _your_ code run and not provide API descriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search on discord.py docs you would find this from guild's object.

```
await create_text_channel(name, *, overwrites=None, category=None, reason=None, **options)
```

Example:

```
guild = client.get_guild(ID)
await guild.create_text_channel('logs')
```

If you want the bot for everyone to use, you would need a database to save channels' id.

About the type of logs that you want to send to each guild it really depends. If it is only logs that you write by your own then just loop all channel's id that you saved and send each one a message.

If it is some discord logs given by discord API then you would have to search in discord.py docs for more info.